# Adding counts and percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add both counts and percentages to a bar chart in R with ggplot2. I found the following example but it doesn't seem to be working. Thank you.

```
(ggplot(mtcars, aes('factor(cyl)', fill='factor(cyl)'))
 + geom_bar()
 + geom_text(
     aes(label='stat(count)'),
     stat='count',
     nudge_x=-0.14,
     nudge_y=0.125,
     va='bottom'
 )
 + geom_text(
     aes(label='stat(prop)*100', group=1),
     stat='count',
     nudge_x=0.14,
     nudge_y=0.125,
     va='bottom',
     format_string='({:.1f}%)'
 )
)
```

Source: https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/miscellaneous-show-counts-and-percentages-for-bar-plots.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the example is written for python's plotnine library (which basically python's ggplot2). You tagged your question with R and ggplot2, so I here is my best translation of the python code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label=after_stat(count)),
    stat='count',
    nudge_x=-0.14,
    nudge_y=0.125,
    vjust = 0
  ) + geom_text(
    aes(label=after_stat(prop * 100), group=1),
    stat='count',
    nudge_x=0.14,
    nudge_y=0.125,
    vjust = 0
  )
```

[image]

For the parenthesis and percentage sign you could use the following:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label=after_stat(count)),
    stat='count',
    nudge_x=-0.14,
    nudge_y=0.125,
    vjust = 0
  ) + geom_text(
    aes(label= after_stat(scales::percent(prop, prefix = "(", suffix = "%)")), 
        group=1),
    stat='count',
    nudge_x=0.14,
    nudge_y=0.125,
    vjust = 0
  )
```

Also @sambold's suggestions in the comments are excellent.

Comment: Oh very good, can you please share how to add parentheses and % for the percentages?

Comment: you could use paste() in the label part ... paste(after_stat(count),"%") or paste("(",after_stat(prop * 100),")")

Answer (score 2):

I don't use ggplot, but it seems they have changed the api. again. Shocking

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = sprintf('%s (%.1f%%)', after_stat(count), after_stat(count / sum(count) * 100))),
    stat='count', vjust = -1
  )
```

[image]